# Select statement with multiple rows/same column - WHERE has multiple variables and is FROM same table

Tags: php, sql, select

I just realized I may have missed the boat on some of my queries. On some parts of my site I have $sql variables that retrieve values from different rows of the same column from the same table, but have different variables in the WHERE clause:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id1'";
$sql2 = "SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id2'";

$result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql1));
$result1a = $result1['login_id'];

$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql2));
$result2a = $result2['login_id'];
```

Since I am SELECTing from the same table, isn't there some way to combine $sql1 and $sql2 and the $result variables, something like the following?

```
$sql = "SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id1' AS 'first', login_id = 
'$login_id2' AS 'second'";

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
$result1 = $result['first']; //uses $login_id1
$result2 = $result['second']; //uses $login_id2
```

An alternative would be something like:

```
$sqlAlt = "SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE (login_id = '$login_id1' OR login_id =   
'$login_id2')";
```

except I don't know how I would extract from $sqlAlt (using mysqli_fetch_assoc or perhaps some other function) the login_id only using the variable $login_id1 or $login_id2; something like

```
$result1 = $sqlAlt['login_id'] //WHERE $result1 is from $login_id1
$result2 = $sqlAlt['login_id'] //WHERE $result2 is from $login_id2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for both login_ids in one query with an `OR` in your SQL:

`SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id1' OR login_id = '$login_id2';`

or even

`SELECT login_id FROM login WHERE login_id IN ('$login_id1', '$login_id2');`

This will return more than one rows. To get those, return a mysql query result from `mysqli_query()` and, after checking that it's not an error and has more than 0 rows, you can loop over it in a `while()` to get the returned rows one at a time:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) ;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $currentResult = $result['login_id'] ;
}
```

Once you get this working, seriously consider reading up about prepared statements and [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for your database interactions. They are the better way to do this, from all aspects.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT login_id AS FIRST FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id1' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT login_id AS SECOND FROM login WHERE login_id = '$login_id2'";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: This query returns two rows with a column names `FIRST`.  That does not seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: OK Thanks...I will try this. Out of curiosity, is the $sql statement you wrote 1 query of the database, or is UNION a command that incorporates (in this case) 2 queries of the database?

Comment: It's two queries combined as one: Executing them as UNION ALL would only involve 1 time going through the database instead of two times.

Comment: Just had a chance to try this...did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run this query:

```
SELECT login_id 
FROM login
WHERE login_id in ('$login_id1', '$login_id2)';
```

This will return *two* rows, each with a `login_id` column.  You need to loop through them.

Along the way, you should also learn about parameterizing queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.